# TabBar does not work after hidden = NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, uitabbar

I am faced a problem: after command self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES, I do something and then call: self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO, tabs do not work at all. It looks like frozen

```
- (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {

        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = TRUE;

        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;


    }
    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = FALSE;

}
```

after pressing Cancel tab bar is appearing but tabs do not work at all

Comment: You will need to provide more information and probably some code snippets if you want some useful feedback on this problem.

Comment: You aren't using `YES` and `NO`. You are using `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Use `YES` and `NO` with `BOOL` types.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I am using YES and TRUE or NO and FALSE, the result the same

Comment: I figured out that this problem appears when I am using camera.

Comment: May be a camera has own 'self'?

Comment: If you work with camera in your app the most probably you need to do any UI changes on the main queue with asynch dispatch. But cannot say from this sample.